# Basic Android: How to display string of user input?

Tags: java, android

I tried to make an app about user inputs the last name, first name and address. What i was trying to do was to let the user input in an `EditText` and display it on a `TextView` but i cannnot display the following text because there is an error on runtime. What it does is if i click the submit button it will display the user input but what it says on the `TextView` is "android.support.v7.widget.TextView....etc".
I just started Android programming now and everything is confusing. Please tell me the most basic stuff to solve this problem.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            EditText fname, lname;
            TextView display;
            Button result;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
                lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastname);
                display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
                result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);



                result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        display.setText("Name: " + lname + ", " + fname);
                    }
                });
        }

    }
```

Comment: just 

call display.setText("Name: " + lname.getText() + ", " + fname.getText());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined correct the variables, but you have to get the value of what the edit text has. so replace your code with this.

```
 result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         display.setText("Name: " + lname.getText().toString() + ", " + fname.getText().toString());
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch the text from the `EditText` widgets when you want to show it in the `TextView`. Right now you just print the object into the `setText`.

Try this instead.

```
display.setText("Name: " + lname.getText().toString() + ", " + fname.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your are not fetching the text of `EditText`. Fetch the text of the `EditText` using **lname.getText().toString()** and then set this text to your `TextView`

Try this code:

```
result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         display.setText("Name: " + lname.getText().toString() + ", " + fname.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lname and fname are EditText you cant concatenate 2 EditText with string.

You need to do

```
display.setText("Name: " + lname.getText() + ", " + fname.getText());
```

Comment: If you call the function toString(), then you dont concatenate 2 EditText you concatenate 2 String.

String toString()

it returns String, so as i said before, you CANT concatenate 2 EditText with String.

Comment: I suggest you give it a try and see what happens

Comment: It's the reason why the topic was created, he tried to concatenate string with 2 edittext and he had errors.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to modularize your code.

First create a bean class which contains fName and lName as two string field and overides toString() method as below.

```
class Person {
    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    // Getter and Setter methods, which you can write.

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + lname + ", " + fname;
    }
}
```

Create bean object and put listener on your both edittext in activty.

```
Person person = new Person();

fname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            //set bean object field fName here. 
            person.setFname(s.toString());
          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
```

same for other edittext field.

```
lname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

              public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                //set bean object field lName here. 
                person.setLName(s.toString());
              }

              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
           });
```

Then inside onclick listener simply return person object toString() method.

```
result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        display.setText(person.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

to build upon Hugo Houyez answer

```
display.setText(String.format("Name: %1$s, %2$s",lname.getText().toString(),fname.getText().toString);
```

now you can see the full string you want to show as first value.

per %s value you can add a string value. the %1$s value means that the first string will be showed here %2$s will show the second string and so forth.